# Free or portable app to organize photos by metadata

Tags: windows, photography, portable, metadata

Are there any free or portable applications that can organize photos and filter them by metadata and other parameters. I would also like the option to adjust the metadata for better organization. I am currently using XnView, but would like to know if there are other free or portable applications that can accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.